# How to disable Next.js scripts, `NEXT_DATA` and React rehydration in NestJS 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

How would I do [this](https://gist.github.com/alexshyba/0d77d41fe5ffadbde0ce61a935c17a23) but for NestJS using app router?